# Python mechanize - find form on Gmail

Tags: python, mechanize

With python and mechanize I normally can find all forms on a website with:

```
for form in br.forms():
print "Form name:", form.name
print form
```

But on [link](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en), I can't find any forms? Is there a way to do so with python and mechanize? (I know there is a captcha and its tough to analyse with cv)

Edit: There should be a form, but i can't find it with `br.select_form(name="createaccount")`:

[image: forms]

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you shouldn't do that, captchas are created originally to block massive account creation.

I never saw any technique to break googles captcha, they are extremely hard.  If you want to throw the captcha to the user (simply create a easy way to create a gmail account), than you can get the form by

```
form = br.select_form(name="createaccount")
```